# Attribute pagespeed_url_hash not allowed on element img at this point

Tags: html, validation, mod-pagespeed

I am using [mod-pagespeed](http://modpagespeed.com/) from Google, and it is adding the attribute `pagespeed_url_hash` to my images. This is not a problem for me, this is just what the modpagespeed is suppose to do, however complying with WC3 HTML5 standards is another story. They are throwing off errors here saying: `Attribute pagespeed_url_hash not allowed on element img at this point.`

The error is thrown on every image with the hash in it (see example below)

```
<img src="https://a.url.to.an.image.com/34643435.jpg" alt="An Image" pagespeed_url_hash="1868320125">
```

If the `pagespeed_url_hash` was instead `data-pagespeed_url_hash` there wouldn't be WC3 errors. So is there anything I can do about this problem, or do I just have to leave it?

Comment: Why do you need it to strictly validate? You are trying to target browsers, not a W3C validator, isn't that correct?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I don't need it to strictly validate, it just would be nice :)

Comment: I wouldn't bother. There was a validation fad a while back... but I think it's generally understood these days that only the actual user agents really matter, and validators tend to reflect the real user agents very poorly.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan this is for personal work, however at my job I do need to usually validate my sites I work on as we must comply with [AODA](http://www.aoda.ca/) and that involves complying with [WCAG from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)

Comment: A website can be perfectly accessible without passing a third party validator. If that law actually requires that it successfully validate, that would be very annoying/disappointing. Anyway, if it comes down to it, you could probably change these attribute to whatever you want by modifying this file: https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/source/browse/trunk/src/net/instaweb/htmlparse/html_name.gperf?r=3015&spec=svn3041

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I don't think it requires it to pass the W3C validator for HTML5 specs, but it would require a pass on the accessibility part, however I think this issue would be fine. It isn't a big deal to fix this in my code as this is just a personal project anyway.